# What is the set of all German articles?

Tags: article

I have been searching for a defintive list of German articles but all such articles on the internet are flooded with introductory texts, mentioning only *der* und *ein*.

As far as I can recall, there were 12 articles. I remember *der, ein, kein,* Personalpronomen, *welch, solch, jen, alle, beide.* Are there any more?

Comment: If you ask me, the articles are "der" and "ein" but you can extend the list to "der", "die", "das", "dem", "den", "des", "ein" and "eine". Anything else isn't an article at all.

Comment: Really? So, what was I taught in class? o_0

Comment: *Article* isn't a well defined technical term. The problem doesn't just exist for German. Your inclusive definition for German would include *no*, *this*, *those*, *yonder* and possibly even *few* among the English articles. But these words are usually called *determiners*. That's a more inclusive linguistic notion. Of course in a school context it may be better to stretch a well-known term than to try introducing a new one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_%28Wortart%29#Formen_der_deutschen_Artikel) is a good overview of all the German articles.

**Der bestimmte Artikel**

```
Kasus     | männlich | weiblich | sächlich | Plural
----------------------------------------------------
Nominativ | der      | die      | das      | die
Genitiv   | des      | der      | des      | der
Dativ     | dem      | der      | dem      | den
Akkusativ | den      | die      | das      | die
```

**Der unbestimmte Artikel**

```
Kasus     | männlich | weiblich | sächlich | Plural
----------------------------------------------------
Nominativ | ein      | eine     | ein      | -
Genitiv   | eines    | einer    | eines    | –
Dativ     | einem    | einer    | einem    | –
Akkusativ | einen    | eine     | ein      | –
```

There is also a list of [`Possessivartikel`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_%28Wortart%29#Possessivartikel) further down the page.

Comment: There's also an article on articles on [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_articles)

Comment: @Em1 Thanks, great addition.

Comment: Hmm, I knew there is one. But there are some problems with this answer. First, I genuinely am confused which words are articles and which ones are not e.g. einige, viele. And second that I am not a very proficient German reader. So I don't even knoe properly what is written there! I have tried and it feels very painful.

Comment: @AnuragKalia All of them are articles. See the comment by Em1 for the English version.

Comment: Hmm, so is it like English where the and a/an are the only official articles but the role of definitiveness is provided by other words too, say 'this'? I always thought that the words that couldn't be followed by an article couldn't be adjectives but now I realize it is the same with English. And then I realize why are articles made out to be so different at all as a separate ? Their role overlaps too much with adjectives syntactically, after all.

Comment: But now I am again at the starting point since presence or absence of articles change the form of adjectives following them in German. Nothing of sort happens in English. So a list of definite and indefinite articles is indispensable in German to me, but not in English. Is there any other way to solve the declension problem?

Comment: @Baz I am sorry but this link helped me much more when I found it. Moreover, I wasn't looking for declension, sorry!

Comment: Hmm I am sorry. again. It is like my research on articles is never-ending. Turned out, der-words are not articles themselves. So, dies, all, solch etc can technically be used and are used on many occasions with true articles der and ein. I confused declined forms with articles themselves.

Comment: @AnuragKalia As mentioned in my comment to your question there is only a rare set of articles in German. I'd even say we have only two articles, "der" and "ein". You can extend this list including all declension forms (although I forgot to list all declensions of "ein" in my comment above). Everything else is NOT an article. And "Possessivartikel" is a very confusing word...